# contentResolver() openInputStream() - FileNotFoundException (permission denied)

Tags: android, file, permissions, android-contentresolver

When I try to process uri ("file" scheme) I get a FileNotFoundException (Permission denied). It works ok for "content" scheme but not for "file" scheme.

```
    protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    // new ProcessIncomingDataTask().execute(intent);

    try {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if ( uri != null ) {
            InputStream in = null;
            if ( uri.getScheme().equals("file") ) {
                in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

What's wrong?

UPD.

Intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\.pgn" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\.PGN" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\.pgn" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\.PGN" />
        </intent-filter>
```

"tell how you obtained that path"

```
Uri URI = intent.getData()
```

"Also use File.exists() and File.canRead()"

```
File.exists(); // gives "true"
File.canRead(); // gives "false"
```

Comment: Please tell full file scheme. After that tell how you obtained that path. Also use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you invoke the contentResolver.

Comment: blackapps: replied in the problem description update

Comment: Normally data.getData() gives a content scheme. What did you do so you got a file scheme? If you can not read it then you cannot open an inputstream.

Comment: Some file explorers give me the "file" scheme. For example - "X-plore". I don't know why... Recently I'we found the reason why I can't open file. It seems that I need to request runtime permission for reading external storage anyway for "file" scheme. But I thought that Android should give me temporary permissions for this file...

Comment: The file explorer should give you that.

Comment: Probably no. In the case of "file" schema file explorer just gives me the path to this file and that's all. I should ask for permission from the user myself. "Total commander" gives "file" schema too. And this file is also failed to open without permission.